# I have problem with creating cpio archive

Tags: embedded-linux, cpio

I extracted my router firmware using `binwalk` and it give a `cpio` archive that contain rootfs like this

```sh
cpio -it < 639000.cpio    
/dev
/dev/pts
/mnt
/svn.info
/proc
/home
/sbin
...
```

When I recreate the folder using this command

```sh
find * | cpio -H newc -o > /home/kali/Desktop/Share/t.cpio
```

but it shows to me

```
dev
dev/pts
mnt
svn.info
proc
home
sbin
...
```

It doesn't show me the "/" and when I insert this on my router the router wont start and I need to dump it again.

How can I create the file with the "/" behind my main directory?

```
file 639000.cpio  
639000.cpio: ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
```

I tried like all find commend the only commend working good is  `find /`.

But it will find all my base root file of my Linux.

Comment: Take a look at how Buildroot creates the archive for an **initramfs**. Or google `how to create initramfs`

Comment: i dont mean this i mean i have folder i want to make it like the orginal one router

Comment: The original **cpio** archive that you extracted from the router firmware is for the **initramfs**. You're trying to create another **cpio** archive for a modified **initramfs**. So you think you mean something different?

Comment: When I extract the cpio file and I want to compress it again without any changes، I can't create it like the original file I described above.